# Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.SObjectField, Boolean at line 221 column 63

Tags: error-messages

Below is the code. What deoes this error mean.

```
 if((salesRepMapping.Account_Owner__c == true) && (Account.KRM_Program__c == false)){
                a.OwnerId = salesRepMapping.Sales_Rep__c;
            }
```

Comment: What is the type of Account_Owner__c and KRM_Program__c fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the `Account_Owner__c` field or `KRM_Program__c` is not of type boolean, yet you're trying to compare it against a boolean value (true/false). Double check the types of those fields and compare against a value of an appropriate type.